# Java error creating Path from String, does linux limit filenames to 8bit charset

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

My Java code is having problem when a String is converted into an actual Path on a unix system

```
contains unmappable characters: /out/K/Kyuss/?And the Circus Leaves Town/09 - Size Queen.mp3
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: /out/K/Kyuss/?And the Circus Leaves Town/09 - Size Queen.mp3
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.encode(UnixPath.java:147)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:71)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
    at java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2234)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.saveRenamedFile(SongSaver.java:891)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.realSave(SongSaver.java:809)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.saveSongToFile(SongSaver.java:630)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.saveChanges(SongSaver.java:190)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.call(SongSaver.java:165)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.SongSaver.call(SongSaver.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The problem character is the ellipse char '…' (shown as ? in error message output) which is not an 8bit character, but why does it need to be I wasn't aware there was such a restriction on unix systems.

Comment: linux does not like spaces at all (not that it doesnt allow it but they are a pain with some programs in linux and dont work with everything 100%), if you put in an under score instead of space the problem will most likely be solved. or it could be a problem with the `/` and it thinks that is being used in a filename and not a directory path..

Comment: @jgr208 thanks but you are incorrect the issue is with the ellipse char as explained in the question

Comment: was the file meant for a linux machine or was it intended for windows at first?

Comment: @jgr208 its was always intended for linux, but it has a new filename based o constructing filename from metadata, and the metadata contains the eillpse character. But all I want to know is in what circumstances is the ellipse character valid or not valid on linux.

Comment: i just entered an ellipse on my linux system and had no trouble displaying the file name `[root@local untitled folder]# find 
.
./...And the
./...And the/a
`

Comment: @jgr208 yes nor do I , thanks for your help but you are totally misunderstanding my question

Comment: how am I misunderstanding? you are asking if linux OS limits the file name which I don't think linux is the root of the problem it is java that is most likely the root of the problem

Comment: run `echo $LANG` and what is the output.

Comment: @jgr208 its set to nothing !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Linux treats filenames as byte strings. It's the applications that choose to interpret the byte strings however they want. [More info here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/what-charset-encoding-is-used-for-filenames-and-paths-on-linux) Typically programs interpret filenames as UTF-8, but this depends on many factors, including the `LANG` environment variables.

The issue is that Java uses the `LANG` variable to guess what encoding your filenames use. If you don't have it properly set (for example to `en_US.UTF-8`) it might assume your filenames are ASCII, and it refuses to encode the ellipse char since it has no ASCII encoding.

Small example to reproduce it:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("\u2026");
        f.toPath();
    }
}
```

If you run it with `LANG=C` you get the error.

```
$ LANG=C java Test
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: ?
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.encode(UnixPath.java:147)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(UnixPath.java:71)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
    at java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2234)
    at Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

If you run it with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` it works fine.

```
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 java Test
# No crash!
```

If you run it without setting `LANG` it will pick up whatever your system is configured with, which will throw if it doesn't support unicode.

Unfortunately I see no easy way to fix this behavior from your program. `UnixPath.encode` uses `Charset.defaultCharset()` and [there's no way to change it at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding). You'll have to make sure your `LANG` is properly configured.

Comment: Great answer, just waiting for customer to respond to confirm if this is the problem